# leaflet expand control and autoZindex

Tags: javascript, jquery, controls, leaflet, legend

I am trying to keep my leaflet controls expanded and reverse the order it makes my base layers. Currently, the controls only open on hover, and it auto orders my layers 2009-2015. I would like them to go 2015-2009.

I read the documentation here, http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#control-layers-l.control.layers

I understand this should be an easy to do by changing 'collapse' and 'autoZIndex' to false, what am I doing wrong? I feel like there's an easy fix...

Thank you!

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset=utf-8 />
<title>Leaflet layers control</title>
<meta name='viewport' content='initial-scale=1,maximum-scale=1,user-scalable=no' />
<script type="text/javascript" src='https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/v2.1.9/mapbox.js'></script>
    
    <script type="text/javascript" src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js'></script>

<link href='https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/v2.1.9/mapbox.css' rel='stylesheet' />
<style>
  body { margin:0; padding:0; }
  #map { position:absolute; top:0; bottom:0; width:100%; }

    .legend label,
.legend span {
  display:block;
  float:left;
  height:15px;
  width:20%;
  text-align:center;
  font-size:9px;
  color:#808080;
  }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id='legend' style='display:none;'>
    <h1 class="year"><span>Title</span></h1>
  <nav class='legend clearfix'>
    <span style='background:#ecfa00 ;'></span>
    <span style='background:#fdda1d ;'></span>
    <span style='background:#f2a80e;'></span>
    <span style='background:#ff0000 ;'></span>
    <span style='background:#c70606 ;'></span>
    <label>#</label>
    <label>#</label>
    <label>#</label>
    <label>#</label>
    <label>#</label>
    <small><a href="#">Source</a></small>
</div>
<div id='map'></div>

<script>
    
L.mapbox.accessToken = 'apikey_here';
var map = L.mapbox.map('map').setView([40, -96.50], 4);


    
    map.legendControl.addLegend(document.getElementById('legend').innerHTML);
    
    
    
L.control.layers({
    '2015': L.mapbox.tileLayer('map.m885g0j9'),
    '2014': L.mapbox.tileLayer('map.m885oklp'),
    '2013': L.mapbox.tileLayer('map.m889lpb4'),
    '2012': L.mapbox.tileLayer('map.m88a236n'),
    '2011': L.mapbox.tileLayer('map.m88an5o9'),
    '2010': L.mapbox.tileLayer('map.m88aj017'),
    '2009': L.mapbox.tileLayer('map.m88aa5jm').addTo(map)

}           )

    .addTo(map);
    
    
    
var controls = L.control.layers(
 baseLayers, overlayLayers, 
 {
  collapsed: false,
  autoZIndex: false
 }
);
controls.addTo(map);
    
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Since I believe layer ordering in `L.Control.Layers` is still an [open issue](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet/issues/2086), the feature you need only exists in a plugin located at https://github.com/elesdoar/leaflet-control-orderlayers.

Secondly, drop your

```
var controls = L.control.layers(
    baseLayers, overlayLayers, 
    {
        collapsed: false,
        autoZIndex: false
    }
);
controls.addTo(map);
```

It is unneeded. All you need to do is copy your options hash to the first control init, like

```
L.control.layers({
    '2015': L.mapbox.tileLayer('map.m885g0j9'),
    '2014': L.mapbox.tileLayer('map.m885oklp'),
    '2013': L.mapbox.tileLayer('map.m889lpb4'),
    '2012': L.mapbox.tileLayer('map.m88a236n'),
    '2011': L.mapbox.tileLayer('map.m88an5o9'),
    '2010': L.mapbox.tileLayer('map.m88aj017'),
    '2009': L.mapbox.tileLayer('map.m88aa5jm').addTo(map)

},null,  {
    collapsed: false,
    autoZIndex: false
  }          )
```

Comment: Thank you so much! that works to expand it, but you just have to add another  '.addTo(map);' after that last parenthesis. However, the order still isn't reversed.. I'll look into that some more

Comment: Yes, I used the plug in which made the collapsed:false start working, but the autoZindex:false doesn't seem to work...

Answer (score 0):

Could help leaflet-control-orderlayers order option

```js
jQuery(function() {
  var map = L.map('map').setView([4.598056, -74.075833], 13);
  var b1 = L.tileLayer('http://a.tiles.mapbox.com/v3/elesdoar.map-856j4yqh/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
    attribution: 'Map data &copy; <a href="http://openstreetmap.org">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors, <a href="http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/2.0/">CC-BY-SA</a>, Imagery © <a href="http://mapbox.com">Mapbox</a>',
    maxZoom: 20
  });
  var b2 = L.tileLayer('http://a.tiles.mapbox.com/v3/elesdoar.map-lfwx2j04/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
    attribution: 'Map data © OpenStreetMap contributors, CC-BY-SA, Imagery © Mapbox',
    maxZoom: 20
  }).addTo(map);
  var baseLayers = {
    'Night': b2,
    'Streets': b1
  };
  var bogota = L.tileLayer.wms("http://mapas.catastrobogota.gov.co/arcgiswsh/Mapa_Referencia/Mapa_referencia/MapServer/WMSServer", {
    layers: '8,7,6,5,4,2',
    format: 'image/png',
    opacity: 0.45,
    transparent: true,
    attribution: 'Catastro Bogotá http://catastrobogota.gov.co',
    crs: L.CRS.EPSG4326,
    version: '1.3.0'
  }).addTo(map);
  var fire = L.tileLayer('http://openfiremap.org/hytiles/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
    attribution: '© OpenFireMap contributors - © OpenStreetMap contributors',
    continuousWorld: true
  }).addTo(map);
  var overlayLayers = {
    'Bogotá': bogota,
    'OpenFireMap': fire
  };
  var controls = L.control.orderlayers(baseLayers, overlayLayers, {
    collapsed: false,
    order: 'qgis',
    title: 'Layers'
  });
  controls.addTo(map);
  map.setView([4.649, -74.086], 11);
});
```

```css
#map {
  height: 300px;
  width: 600px;
}
.leaflet-control-layers {
  width: 150px;
  padding: 10px !important;
}
.leaflet-control-layers-separator {
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
}
.leaflet-control-layers .leaflet-control-layers-title {
  font-size: 1.2em;
}
.leaflet-control-layers .leaflet-row {
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
}
.leaflet-control-layers .leaflet-row .leaflet-input {
  float: left;
  width: 15%;
}
.leaflet-control-layers .leaflet-row .leaflet-name {
  float: left;
  width: 60%;
}
.leaflet-control-layers .leaflet-row .leaflet-up {
  float: left;
  background-image: url(http://elesdoar.github.io/leaflet-control-orderlayers/images/arrow-up.png);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
  height: 20px;
  width: 16px;
  opacity: 0.75;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.leaflet-control-layers .leaflet-row .leaflet-down {
  float: left;
  background-image: url(http://elesdoar.github.io/leaflet-control-orderlayers/images/arrow-down.png);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
  height: 20px;
  width: 16px;
  opacity: 0.75;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<link href="http://cdn.leafletjs.com/leaflet-0.7.3/leaflet.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdn.leafletjs.com/leaflet-0.7.3/leaflet.js"></script>
<script src="http://elesdoar.github.io/leaflet-control-orderlayers/javascripts/leaflet.control.orderlayers.min.js"></script>

<div id="map"></div>
```

See https://github.com/elesdoar/leaflet-control-orderlayers#options

And compare with http://elesdoar.github.io/leaflet-control-orderlayers/

Comment: Check the addTo at `'Night': b2` layer